# why my data is coming as null or default in ui from view model in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I set up mvvm structure and call two functions in viewmodel. Functions return values, but these values ​​always come as values ​​that I define as null or default.
Why can't I access my data in the view model in the UI?

**I can see the data properly in the view model**

**hear is my code**

**my ui**

```
 if (viewModel.isDialogShown) {

        AlertDialog(
            onDismiss = {
                viewModel.onDismissClick()
            },
            onConfirm = {

                println("First"+viewModel.getFirstConversionRateByCurrency(viewModel.dropDownMenuItem1))
                println("SECOND:"+viewModel.getSecondConversionRateByCurrency(viewModel.dropDownMenuItem2))



            }
        )
    }
```

If the user says confirm in the alert dialog in my UI, these functions are called and I print the returned values ​​for testing purposes, but because I define null as default in the viewmodel, it always comes null.

**my view model**

```
@HiltViewModel
class ExchangeMainViewModel @Inject constructor(
 
    private val getConversionRateByCurrencyUseCase: GetConversionRateByCurrencyUseCase
) : ViewModel() {


    var second : Double?=null
    var first : Double? = null

 
   fun getFirstConversionRateByCurrency(currency:String) : String   {



       viewModelScope.launch {

           first = getConversionRateByCurrencyUseCase.getConversionRateByCurrency(currency)
       }

       return first.toString()
   }

    fun getSecondConversionRateByCurrency(currency:String) :String {


        viewModelScope.launch {


            second =  getConversionRateByCurrencyUseCase.getConversionRateByCurrency(currency)

        }
        return second.toString()

    }

}
```

**Also, I defined the viewmodel in ui as you can see the below like this, could it be because of this?**

```
@Composable
fun DropDownMenu(
    viewModel: ExchangeMainViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
```

**The result in the console is as follows**

[image]

Comment: You’re launching coroutines to fetch the values. A coroutine launches asynchronously, so your function is returning before the coroutine code has been run yet.

Comment: What would you recommend in this case? What approach should I use?

Comment: It depends what you’re using the fetched values for. If they are in your UI, you should change them into MutableState and your UI will recompose when the new values arrive. It certainly does not make sense to return the value from the function that is launching the coroutine.  There is no simple way to log the values from within dialog.onConfirm since it cannot wait for the coroutines. You’d have to do something complicated with turning these into suspend functions that join their launched coroutines at the end, and launch a coroutine in onComplete to call them.

Comment: @NewPartizal I made some changes on your code, I'm not confident that it would work, but that should give you a start, and to add to what Tenfour said, when you open the dialog it might not have a value yet, so the expected case scenario in my answer is you have to wait a bit before showing the dialog

Answer (score 0):

All those functions your are calling are executing a `coroutine` from `viewModelScope.launch{…}` and at the time you launched them you immediately return a value from the method `return.xxx.toString()` where the xxx (`first` and `second`) doesn't have a value yet since what you are expecting is coming from a concurrent execution not a sequential one.

```
viewModelScope.launch { // launch me separately and wait for any value that will set the `first`
   first = getConversionRateByCurrencyUseCase.getConversionRateByCurrency(currency)
}

// return from this function now with a null value, since it was initialized as null
return first.toString()
```

This is a rough implementation, though I'm not sure if this would work, but this should give you a headstart

Your new `ViewModel`

```
@HiltViewModel
class ExchangeMainViewModel @Inject constructor(

    private val getConversionRateByCurrencyUseCase: GetConversionRateByCurrencyUseCase
) : ViewModel() {

    var conversionValue by mutableStateOf<ConversionValues?>(null)

    fun getFirstConversionRateByCurrency(currency:String) {

        viewModelScope.launch {

            val first = getConversionRateByCurrencyUseCase.getConversionRateByCurrency(currency)
            val second = getConversionRateByCurrencyUseCase.getConversionRateByCurrency(currency)

            conversionValue = ConversionValues(first, second)
        }
    }
}
```

the `Data Class` for `first` and `second`

```
data class ConversionValues(
    val first : Double,
    val second: Double
)
```

and your composable

```
@Composable
fun DropDownMenu(
    viewModel: ExchangeMainViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    
    val conversionValue = vieModel.conversionValue

    if (viewModel.isDialogShown) {

        AlertDialog(
            onDismiss = {
                viewModel.onDismissClick()
            },
            onConfirm {

                println("First" + conversionValue.first)
                println("SECOND:"+conversionValue.second)
            }
        )
    }
}
```